# C++ insert symbol if rotation is specific character

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying my luck at decrypting/crypting and I want to insert characters if a said rotation would result in a few specific characters. I have a constant string called CHARS ="ABCXYZabcxyz". My crypted string at the moment is "eDhrS3S0/".

I am using ASCII rotation 4, and if the current string character would be one of my characters from "CHAR" I want to add / before and / after the said character, but I cant get it working, this is my code at the moment for this.

```
const string CHARS="ABCXYZabcxyz";
string crypt = "eDhrS3S0/", encrypted;
    string cryptTemp = crypt;

    for (int i=0; i<cryptTemp.length(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<CHARS.length(); j++){
            if (((int)crypt[i]-4) == (int)CHARS[j]){
                crypt.insert(crypt[i],"0",-1);
                crypt.insert(crypt[i],CHARS[j], 0);
                crypt.insert(crypt[i],"0",+1);
            }
        }
    }
```

I manage to replace the characters if they match chars without rotation, but once I add "-5" in the if statement nothing happens and I am really stuck at this point. The first character in the string "e" should translate to "a" after I remove 4 from it, but I cant get it working.

Comment: Did you _mean_ to have two nested loops that both use `i` as variable?

Comment: Oh no, the second one should be "j", let me edit.

Comment: You said "but once I add "-5" in the if " but in the code you've written -4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some separation of concerns will make your code clearer:

- Pull out the `rot4` code into a separate function.
- Explicitly call this function and assign the result to `c`
- Use `std::string#find` instead of a loop.
- Accumulate all characters in `ret` and return that.

```
char rot4(char c) {
    bool wasupper = isupper(c);
    c = tolower(c);
    int value = int(c - 'a') - 4;
    if (value < 0) value += 26;
    c = value + (wasupper ? 'A' : 'a');
    return c;
}

string decrypt(string crypt) {
    string ret;

    for (int i=0; i<crypt.length(); i++){
        char c = rot4(crypt[i]);
        if (CHARS.find(c) != string::npos) {
            ret += '/';
            ret += c;
            ret += '/';
        } else {
            ret += c;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

As for your original question, I'm pretty sure you were using the wrong overload of `std::string#insert`.

Comment: It's also possible to rotate `CHARS` in the opposite direction and check `crypt` against that. Less work.

Comment: I understood the assignment to be "rotate *all* characters in the input, and if they are in CHARS surround them with /"

Comment: Yes, seems like you would still need to `rot4(crypt[i])`, but only when the character actually matches (or make a lookup table). This really depends on how much performance OP needs.